# Trying to redirect when a service complete his work in Angular 4 application

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-services

I Have a AuthService and I'm calling a signInAction method from a LoginComponent. I would like to redirect when the token is initialized.

How can I perform this ?

Here is a SignIn Method in my auth.service.ts file

```
signInAction(){
        let that = this;
        new Oidc.UserManager(this.config).signinRedirectCallback().then(function (user) {
            that.currentUser = user;
            that.token = user.access_token;
        }).catch(function (e) {
            console.error(e);
        });
      }
```

Here is my LoginComponent File

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.signInAction();
    //Wait until signInAction is complete before navigateByUrl
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/my-profile');
  }
```

/*UPDATED WORKING VERSIONS*/
Thanks to everyone, I learned how Observable work and this is my final working version.

//In the AuthService

```
signInAction(){
    let that = this;
    return Observable.create(observer =>
      new Oidc.UserManager(this.config).signinRedirectCallback().then(function (user) {
          that.currentUser = user;
          that.token = user.access_token;
          observer.next();
          observer.complete();
      }).catch(function (e) {
          console.error(e);
          observer.complete();
      })
    );
  }
```

//In my LoginComponent

```
ngOnInit() { 
    this.authService.signInAction()
      .subscribe(
        () => this.router.navigateByUrl('/my-profile')
      );
  }
```

Comment: As currently written, you can't. There's no way to tell from outside when that process finishes. You could `return` something observable from `signInAction`, then do `this.authService.signInAction().subscribe(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('/my-profile'))`. Or expose the process completion via an event observable, e.g. `this.authService.signInAction(); this.authService.signedIn$.subscribe(...);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there might be better approach to do. But, you can solve this issue for now, using EventEmitter and subscribing to it on component:

`import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';`

In service class define an event emitter and emit event after token update:

```
tokenUpdated = new EventEmitter<void>();

  signInAction() {
    let that = this;
    new Oidc.UserManager(this.config).signinRedirectCallback().then(function (user) {
      that.currentUser = user;
      that.token = user.access_token;
      that.tokenUpdated.emit();
    }).catch(function (e) {
      console.error(e);
    });
  }
```

then, in your component, you can subscribe to it:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.signInAction();
    //Wait until signInAction is complete before navigateByUrl
    this.authService.tokenUpdated
      .subscribe(
        () => this.router.navigateByUrl('/my-profile')
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I will agree with all the answers that will tell you to use observables,  but for the purpose of getting what you have to work,  you can use a simple callback like.

```
this.authService.signInAction((user) => { 
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/my-profile');
});

// ---

signInAction(next){
    let that = this;
    new Oidc.UserManager(this.config)
        .signinRedirectCallback()
        .then(function (user) {
          that.currentUser = user;
          that.token = user.access_token;
          next(user);
```

Comment: this solution is working really well too, but I pretty like the eventImitter . thanks for your solution